# Softlayer API integration with Foreman

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, theforeman

Is there any Softlayer API integration module for the open-source project "The Foreman" (https://theforeman.org/)? The only available integration is external to Softlayer and is not being maintained (https://github.com/jstuart/foreman-softlayer)...

We would like to test Softlayer's cloud offering and we would like to integrate it into our centralized server management platform.

Thank you for the information in advance.

Regards,
Kalin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, the oficial softlayer modules are [here](https://github.com/softlayer), and I did not see a module for "The Foreman"